# how do I pass a variable collected thorough xmlhttp.open to PHP code of origin

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting a screen resolution through XMLHttpRequest. 
I am opening a show_content.php file with screen resolution variables which I pull with the GET Method. This works!

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","show_content.php"+queryString,true);
```

and showing this file with the variables in a following div

```
<div id="txtResolution"></div>
```

This part works as well!

PROBLEM:
This div contains screen resolution variables that I would like to use throught the rest of the code outside of it but I can not pass them. How can I get those variables to be passed to the original code.

I used the GET method but can not pass the variables to the original code outside the show_content.php
I have tried with GLOBALS and Sessions as well but no luck

Here ist the code. Everything works properly but I can not pass the variables from the "txtResolution" div to the rest of the code

```
function showResolution(field_id)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (field_id.length==0)
{ 
 document.getElementById("txtResolution").innerHTML="";
 return;
 }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("myvalue").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
var myphpvar = document.getElementById('myvalue').innerText;
}
}

var winW = 630, winH = 460;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
document.documentElement &&
document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
 winH = window.innerHeight;
}
  var queryString = "?width=" + winW + "&height=" + winH;



 xmlhttp.open("GET","show_content.php"+queryString,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume show_content.php contains some HTML markup and some php var you want to use in your JavaScript code.
You may just put php var content somewhere in hidden div inside markup returned by show_content.php:

show_content.php:

```
<?
$myvar = $_REQUEST['width'] +  $_REQUEST['height'];
// send myvar to response:
print '<div style="display:none" id="myvalue">'.htmlspecialchars($myvar).'</div>';
?>
```

Then put following code to your javascript, just after `...innerHtml = xmlhttp.responseText;` (see comment)

```
function showResolution(field_id)
{
  var xmlhttp;
  if (field_id.length == 0)
  {
    document.getElementById("txtResolution").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById("txtResolution").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      // Extract myvar value from php
      var myphpvar = document.getElementById('myvalue').innerText;
      alert('Var from php:'+myphpvar);
    }
  }

  var winW = 630, winH = 460;
  if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth)
  {
    winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
    winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
  }

  if (document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat' &&
      document.documentElement &&
      document.documentElement.offsetWidth)
  {
    winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
    winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  }

  if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight)
  {
    winW = window.innerWidth;
    winH = window.innerHeight;
  }

  var queryString = "?width=" + winW + "&height=" + winH;

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "show_content.php" + queryString, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

For sure, much better to use some kind of JSON with data in response and do not mix html and data in AJAX.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question since it does not seem I have clarified my problem properly.

Comment: I got it now what you wrote. Unfortunately I do not know what to do with `var myphpvar = document.getElementById(‘myvalue’).innerText;`

Comment: I provided full javascript code with comment, hope it will be more descriptive

Comment: `alert('Var from php:'+myphpvar);` alerts nothing although I have a value in `<div id="myvalue">`

Comment: I have edited quotes in php code (grammar corrector put the wrong ones). Please check that you use correct quotes in your code. You may type `alert(document.getElementById('myvalue').innerText);` in browser debug console (usually activated by F12 key) manually after your request completed to see that value avaialable? BTW what browser do you use?

Comment: i have seen the quotes problem right away and changed it. I am using chrome. I can not get the value this way. I did something else though: instead of using `document.getElementById("txtResolution").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` i have used `document.getElementById("myvalue").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` - this way I could get the value I need. How can I use this value from `var myphpvar` in my code now. I have changed it in my original code so you can see what does it look like now.,

Comment: I have created JS fiddle to demonstrate the working code https://jsfiddle.net/1Lp2rw7g/7/